# Save Uploaded Image to exisitng Model in Django

Tags: python, django, file, web, server

I am using a Form to Upload a picture via dropzone.js. The picture gets saved and uploaded fine. But it's creating a new model with empty fields.. I want to save the picture to that existing model I'm referencing to. But I can't seem to find a solution to reference it. Here's my code:

**views.py** (I guess the error is in here)

```
def client_view(request, pk):
client = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=pk)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        picture = form.save()

    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

    data = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response('client_view.html', locals(),     RequestContext(request), {"img": picture})

return render(request, 'client_view.html', {'client': client})
```

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'^client/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', client_view, name='client_view'),
```

**forms.py**

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('image',)
```

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
customer_nr = models.IntegerField(null=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
birthdate = models.DateField(null=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
image = models.ImageField("Image", upload_to='files/%Y/%m', null=True, blank=True)
```

**client_view.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'client_view' pk=client.pk %}" class="dropzone"     id="myDropzone">

    {% csrf_token %}

<div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple/>
</div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    paramName: "image",
    autoProcessQueue : true,
    parallelUploads: 1,

    init: function() {

        this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {

            console.log(responseText);

        });

    }

    };



</script>
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Django specified way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) is to instantiate the `ModelForm` using an existing model:

In your **views.py**:

```
client = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=pk)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, client)
    if form.is_valid():
        picture = form.save()

else:
    form = UploadFileForm(client)
```

For a `POST` request, this will automatically save the image to the correct model.

For a `GET` request, this will attach the image currently associated with the model, if any, to the form field before it is sent to be rendered on a browser.

Comment: @Progph [On thanking in the comment section](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126184)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, don't use

```
form.save()
```

Because it is creating a new instance in the model. Rather I would like to suggest something like-

```
def client_view(request, pk):
    client = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            client.image = form.cleaned_data.get('image', None)
            picture = client.save()

        else:
            form = UploadFileForm()

        data = {'form': form}
        return render_to_response('client_view.html', locals(), RequestContext(request), {"img": picture})

    return render(request, 'client_view.html', {'client': client})
```